# Why shouldn't Chang'e 5's lander's propellant freeze?

Tags: fuel, chang-e, hypergolics

> We have just measured the shape of the crater that the returner landed on, which is part of the scientific data collection. Then the returner will [put on a] 'new warm coat' **to prevent the remaining propellant inside from being frozen** during the transportation to Zhurihe Airport, where the propellant will be expelled from [the] returner," said Cao Ruiqiang, a space product assurance assistant, in a [China Central Television interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Blc42OZihlc) (1:29-1:35).

Why should the propellant avoid freezing?  Cooler generally means slower chemical reactions, so safer.  There may be a language barrier here, but the propellants on the returner (lander) may have been hypergolic.  Apollo's hypergolics tolerated temperatures colder than those at Chang'e's [landing point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_Mongolia#Climate).

Comment: Possibly related (I don't know what propellant Chang'e uses): https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32580/6944

Comment: There's not that many practical choices for storable hypergolic propellants, but beyond that, it's water that's unusual in expanding when it freezes, so the "superpacking" issue can be expected to be a general problem with freezing propellants.